# How can we save these questions about cross breeds?

Tags: discussion

"These questions", asked by different people, are [Can sub-races breed and produce half-subraces?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97766/) and [Which are races, and which are species?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67962/), closed as "opinion based" and "unclear what you're asking".

Honestly, I have no idea, how can it be "unclear".

In every particular setting there are finite number of species (which are traditionally called "races"). Some of them can naturally interbreed, others can not. In the end of the day, the questions are:

- What species are able to create hybrid offspring?
- Would be that offspring infertile?

I agree that you can ask this only in context of a particular setting. If the setting wasn't explicitly specified though, the question can be answered like "this setting has various interbreeds, and this one has only half-orcs and half-elves". So these questions *are* answerable.

However, the only related question that wasn't closed was [How could I play a Half-Dwarf Half-Elf?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69761/), and the answer was "use the 'Creating a Race' chapter of DMG, page 285", so it actually didn't answer were there dwarf-elf hybrids *in the world* or not.

**Racial traits are base properties of a setting.** If you play, let's say, a faerunian setting, you can't just "make up" such important details. There are different species. Some of them are intelligent, others are not. Some of them can interbreed, others can not. There are official sources, describing how are the things going in the world, for this particular setting. I don't understand how can it be "opinion based".

Answers can vary between editions, I thought, so I've asked [What D&D editions describe any hybrids of non-human races?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103530/) This one was closed as "too broad".

How can we improve these questions to make them answerable? Or would it be better to ask another one?

Comment: One more datum to (possibly) consider, from the author of your second example: I quickly came to agree that it isn't a good question.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast edited, thank you

Comment: @nitsua60 that's why I'm asking "how to improve it"

Comment: Often when people work on "saving" a question they wind up replacing it with a totally different one that's just thematically similar. That's a bit like if an emergency room surgeon just shot his patient, threw the corpse away, got another perfectly healthy person to lie down in the same bed, then declared "ta-da! He's cured!". At that point all that's really saved is the question ID; the question itself was disposed of. Be mindful that if whilst improving the question you find you're just replacing it wholesale, you might as well just ask a new question at that point, which is fine.

Comment: @doppelgreener what is your suggestion, related to these two questions?

Comment: If the setting isn't specified in the question, the question *is* unanswerable: GMs can just make up homebrew settings, and even the number of published D&D settings is so great that no-one is an expert on them all.

Answer (score 7):

## Detail the problem and request a family-friendly solution

To salvage such questions, they should include a description of the problem that needs solving. Idle curiosity is fine to a point, but when it's idle curiosity about *breeding*, folks' buttons get pushed, especially if indulging that curiosity requires an answer that delves into topics unsuitable for nonadults.

- In the case of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/97766/8610), comments encouraged the asker to edit into the question the problem that needs solving. At the time of this answer, the asker hasn't.
- On the other hand, [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67962/8610) demands research across multiple editions of [dungeons-and-dragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) so as to compile breeding information, but how that information will be *used* remains a mystery. At the time of this answer, there's no *problem* except that the asker doesn't have the information.

Both questions would benefit from a description of the problem, starting with explaining how the question applies to a campaign the asker's involved in or planning.

Also, I've asked a breeding [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51657/8610) myself and emphasized that answers be kept family-friendly, and that's not because I'm a prude or anything but because I want answers to take the question seriously. Such an inclusion in any breeding question is probably a good idea if only so the asker isn't perceived as possessing unusual predilections (not that there's anything *wrong* with that—this is the Internet, after all).

Comment: Is it wrong intent to make your campaign in the faerunian setting, not faerun-ish? Why do we need a particular problem in order to clarify base setting features, like species?

Comment: @enkryptor I'm not sure how I implied that at all, but of course it's not *wrong* to do whatever you want in your own campaign! I also doubt anyone has an issue with a question about changing Faerûnian ecology. However, questions about sex—and that is what all 3 questions linked to in this answer are about—must clear a higher bar due to their very nature. That's not *my* judgment, by the way, but my experience with the site.

Comment: @enkryptor That's the first time Faerûn has been mentioned in connection with any of these questions. Do you see how that just highlights that there *is* information missing about the goal/problem?